# Use SQL Server Variable in Codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I Have SQL, When I run it on Sql Editor its Work, but any problem when I run it on Codeigniter

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(c.ADD_TIME,0,9)) 
            FROM TDS_PROD_TRANS c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
set @query='SELECT *,'+@cols+' FROM (
    SELECT PT.DEFECT_NO,SUBSTRING(PT.ADD_TIME,0,9) AS ADD_DATE,SUM(PT.QTY) QTY,
    PT.DEFECT_NM,ISNULL(L.LIB_NM, ''OTHER'') AS AREA_NM
    FROM TDS_PROD_TRANS PT
    LEFT JOIN TDS_DEFECT TD ON PT.DEFECT_NO=TD.DEFECT_NO AND TD.STOP_MK=''N''
    LEFT JOIN CMN_LIBRARY L ON TD.DEFECT_DESC=L.LIB_NO AND L.KIND=''AREA'' AND L.STOP_MK=''N''
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(PT.ADD_TIME,0,9),PT.DEFECT_NO,PT.DEFECT_NM,L.LIB_NM
)TBL
PIVOT(SUM(QTY) FOR  ADD_DATE IN('+@cols+')) AS ER'
execute(@query);
```

When I run it on CI its just show selected column only without pivot column, Here my code on CI

```
function defectDailyQuery(){
    $this->dev = $this->load->database("DEV", TRUE);
    return $this->dev->query("
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(c.ADD_TIME,0,9)) 
            FROM TDS_PROD_TRANS c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
set @query='SELECT *,'+@cols+' FROM (
    SELECT PT.DEFECT_NO,SUBSTRING(PT.ADD_TIME,0,9) AS ADD_DATE,SUM(PT.QTY) QTY,
    PT.DEFECT_NM,ISNULL(L.LIB_NM, ''OTHER'') AS AREA_NM
    FROM TDS_PROD_TRANS PT
    LEFT JOIN TDS_DEFECT TD ON PT.DEFECT_NO=TD.DEFECT_NO AND TD.STOP_MK=''N''
    LEFT JOIN CMN_LIBRARY L ON TD.DEFECT_DESC=L.LIB_NO AND L.KIND=''AREA'' AND L.STOP_MK=''N''
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(PT.ADD_TIME,0,9),PT.DEFECT_NO,PT.DEFECT_NM,L.LIB_NM
)TBL
PIVOT(SUM(QTY) FOR  ADD_DATE IN('+@cols+')) AS ER'
execute(@query);
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no body answer , so i decide to manage data on backend